# How can I send email using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios

I am very new to iPhone development.
In my app, I want to send email using MFMailComposeViewController while clicking a button.

How can I achieve this?
I used the code below.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

[controller setSubject:@"Email App"];

[controller setMessageBody:@"Sample email app" isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES]; // App crash in this line.

[controller release];
```

It is showing this warning:

```
'ImportingDocumentAppDelegate' may not respond to '-presentModalViewController:animated:'.
```

Thanks.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Arun `presentModalViewController` is the method of `UIViewController` so you cann't call it on app delegate instance. Add a UIViewController's view to your window then call this method on that view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that you are telling your app delegate to present the view.  You need to call this function on a [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926).